# get list of Square transactions made through an app using Oauth

Tags: square-connect

Reg. Square Connect API: ListTransactions API: as accessToken is used as part of the API call, does Square respond with the entire list of transactions of the merchant (my app is using Oauth) for a given location or only a subset of transactions - initiated by an app.

Comment: What kind of application are you working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-listtransactions) endpoint will list all the transactions for a location. You can not query by application at this time.